# Minimum PD under Basel II retail asset?

Tags: risk, risk-management, risk-models

I have been told that under Basel II the minimum PD that one can assign to any portfolio/segment classified under the retail asset class is 0.33%.

But Google searches return nothing and I can't seem to find any references to it in the accord document?

Is this true and where is it mentioned in the accord?

Comment: what does PD mean ?

Comment: @Probilitator: I would guess "probability of default".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Basel II accord](http://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs128b.pdf):

285. For corporate and bank exposures, the PD is the greater of the one-year PD
     associated with the internal borrower grade to which that exposure is assigned, or 0.03%.

So it is 0.03%